# Sysinternals Handles Close Command?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, sysinternals

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle >>> I downloaded the file on this site. Everything is fine but I cannot do exactly what I want. I explained exactly what I wanted with video. I'm coding an application. I have set this up to work via CMD. How can I close the specified directory with a single code from CMD? I want to do this without needing a handles-id. I want to prepare this as a code. Please help me. :(

This code works like this. But I want to do this without needing a handle-id.

```
handle -c 0x1a2c -p Notepad.exe
```

I want to do it this way. But it doesn't work.

```
handle -c C:\Users\dream -p notepad.exe
```

I want to do it like in this video. How do I do this with the cmd command? I just want to specify a handles-directory. Sample:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC2-5PPpLBo

Comment: As you say, handles only works with a hex value. You would need to find the handles associated with the file and also deal with the situation when a process has more than one handle on the same file.

Comment: You are going to have to use either `handle -a` or `handle -p notepad` to first *list* all the handles and then use another tool such as `grep` or a powershell equivalent to cycle through the handles you want.

Comment: https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/2956/how-to-manage-open-file-handles-with-powershell/

Comment: Finally I found someone who understands me. :( Thank you.

Finding a pid is easy. Difficult to remove handles attached to just a sample exe. I want to do this without needing handle-id.

Can you send me a sample code for this? I am very newbie. I would really appreciate it. I love you. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like handle only accepts pid's these days, i.e. `handle -c 33C -p 109004 -y`

Answer (score 2):

**Danger!** Forcing handles closed can cause [cascade failure and data corruption](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd547078(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in the target process.

If you want to do it anyway, you can use the below PowerShell script. It takes two arguments: the name of the process to target, then the path to the file/directory to close the handle(s) to. It requires the `handle` utility to be placed in the same directory.

```
$targetPid = $null
$targetFile = $args[1]
.\handle -p $args[0] | % {
    If ($_ -match 'pid: (\d*) ') {
        $targetPid = $Matches[1]
    } ElseIf ($_ -match '([0-9A-F]*): File.{10}(.*)') {
        If ($Matches[2] -eq $targetFile) {
            .\handle -c $Matches[1] -p $targetPid -y | Out-Null
        }
    }
}
```

First, it invokes `handle` to list the handles of the target process. It then loops over the lines of output, parsing them with [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). When it sees a line that specifies the target process's PID, it notes that for later use. When it later sees a line about a file handle, it checks whether the file is the one specified as a command-line argument and, if so, invokes `handle` again to close it.

If the script is saved as `handleclose.ps1`, you can run it from a command prompt like this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c .\handleclose.ps1 TargetProcess.exe 'C:\path\to\file'
```

**Tip:** If you're looking for a GUI way to see and close handles, Sysinternals [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to kill a process where the name of the executable and the path of some file in use are found, they coincide in a given PID ...

In command line:

```bat
wmic process where "name like '%notepad.exe%' and commandline like '%C:\\Users\\dream%'" delete
```

In bat/cmd file:

```bat
wmic process where "name like '%%notepad.exe%%' and commandline like '%%C:\\Users\\dream%%'" delete
```

In PowerShell using *`Get-WmiObject`*:

```bat
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | % { if ($_.ProcessName -like '*Notepad.exe*' -and $_.CommandLine -like '*C:\Users\dream*') {kill $_.ProcessId}}
```

Using *`Get-CimInstance Win32_Process`*:

```bat
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name='notepad.exe'" | % { if ($_.CommandLine -like '*C:\Users\dream*') {kill $_.ProcessId}}

# Or.... 
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name='notepad.exe'" | 
% { if ($_.CommandLine -like '*C:\Users\dream*') {kill $_.ProcessId}}
```

[image]

**Additional resources:**

- ***[`wmic /? | www.ss64.com`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/get-process-owner-and-other-info-with-wmi-and-powershell/)***
- ***[`Win32_Process` | Some usage examples](https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_process)***
- ***[Get Process Owner and Other Info with WMI and PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/get-process-owner-and-other-info-with-wmi-and-powershell/)***

Answer (score -1):

Using the csv output and powershell, it's pretty straightforward.  These days you need the numeric PID to close a handle, otherwise you'll just get the usage help message.  Handle64.exe may crash doing these, and the only option may be to reboot to run handle again as the same user.  The yes/no prompt doesn't work over invoke-command.

```
handle js2010 -p emacs -nobanner -v | convertfrom-csv

Process : emacs.exe
PID     : 12616
Type    : File
Handle  : 0x00000040
Name    : C:\Users\js2010
```

It's asking y/n and I answer n.  $name and $process can be partial matches.

```
$name = 'js2010'
$process = 'emacs'

handle $name -p $process -nobanner -v | convertfrom-csv | 
  % { handle -nobanner -c $_.Handle -p $_.PID }

   40: File          C:\Users\js2010
Close handle 40 in emacs.exe (PID 12616)? (y/n) n

Handle close aborted.
```